# How can I share my raspberry pi 3's internet to a router's WAN port?

Tags: networking, share

I would like to share my 4GLTE within my home network by tethering from my phone through USB. The reason is because I have other devices that need to communicate with each other without the need for Internet.

The following setup works without a problem:
*Android USB Tethering* >*Windows PC*>*Router WAN port*

Now, I would like to do the same thing on the raspberry pi so it's as follows:

*Android USB Tethering*>*Raspberry pi USB port*---*Raspverry pi eth0*>*Router WAN*

The problem seems I don't know how I can share or simply allow traffic from USB to eth0 to pass through.

I followed a lot of tutorials and none of them worked.

The best I found that I understood involved installing bridging utils and setting up the br0 interface but that doesn't work either. I'm thinking the RPI3 has to dish out IPs.

Also, the router [Linksys 4200] does have a USB port and is running DD-WRT but I hear the USB support is for USB modems only. It doesn't work.

Comment: So from the Pi are you able to browse the web over your 4g connection?

Comment: Yes I can access the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I was able to get it to work.

Things to note:

- With current version of Raspbian (JESSE/LITE), the use of `/etc/network/interfaces` is obsolete. But keep it as it is used by `if-up` and `if-down` scripts.

---

**My Setup**

- Gave Raspberry Pi's ***eth0*** a static IP address, connected to router's WAN port.
- Gave router a static IP address on the same network with the Raspberry Pi as the gateway.
- Installed **dnsmasq** [`sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`] on the Raspberry Pi.
- Configured packet forwarding [`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`] in `/etc/sysctl.conf`
- Configured routing using `iptables`

  - `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o usb0 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`. **usb0** is the source interface. One can add a `post-up` script in **/etc/network/interfaces** to automate this.

---

**Configuring the static IP address static in /etc/dhcpcd.conf**

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Also don't forget to enable IP forwarding.

Comment: Doesn't bridging do essentially that?

Comment: I've been having trouble with the latest Raspbian version (Pixel). I asked in the forums and it turns out you have to use dhcpd.conf for that.

Comment: did you disable DHCP server on the Router and used one on the Raspberry Pi instead?

Comment: `Gave router a static IP address on the same network with the Raspberry Pi as the gateway.` Did you do this in the (http?) configuration of the router? Should I expect all routers to accept a setting for what to use as gateway?

Comment: @RhoPhi I assigned the router 's WAN port interface a static IP address, and the RPI as the gateway. So, if your raspbery PIs **eth0** is 192.168.1.1 then your router's WAN interface could be 192.168.1.2 and the gateway 192.168.1.1 So technically yes.

Comment: Since the router sees the RPI as the gateway, that's why I installeld DNSMASQ on it to handle address resolution and all that jazz.

Comment: @RhoPhi By `HTTP` you mean web console? Then yes. I think that's the most common way routers expose their configuration parameters.

Comment: @chx101 I think the culprit is this setting of gateway on the router for the WAN connection. For me the WAN configuration offers only some choice for ISP-related parameters to pick public static or dynamic IP.

Comment: @RhoPhi Yes. It's the same for any and every interface. You specify your static IP and the DNS/Gateway server. If your router doesn't give you those options then you might want to get rid of it and get a new one because it doesn't serve your best interests. Honestly, that sounds fishy and scary. It means your router has a hardwired gateway address. Or you don't know where to find that setting.